# Reverse an Array (not using reverse) - map & unshift - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to reverse an array without using reverse and I can't work out why my code isn't working.
If you could help at all that would be great thanks.

```
let inverse = [];
inverse = array.map( element => inverse.unshift(element) )
```

If you could help at all that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need no mapping, just iterating.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    reverse = [];

array.forEach(v => reverse.unshift(v));

console.log(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  size = array.length,
  result = array.map((_, i, arr) => arr[size - i - 1]);

console.log(result);
```